# Having trouble while split alphanumeric string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2016, and I have a table A

```
ID            Comments
-------------------------------
1             John$123
2             Bret$45 33-4ABC
3             HELEN$150-KLR
4             NULL
```

I need an output as shown here:

```
ID            Comments              Amount
------------------------------------------
1             John                  123
2             Bret                   45
3             HELEN                 150
4             NULL                  NULL
```

Code is here, but I get an error

> Invalid length parameter is passed to left or substring

Code:

```
select 
    a.*, v.comments, 
    left(v.rest, patindex('%[^$0-9]%', rest + ' ') - 1) as amount
from 
    a 
cross apply
    (values (rtrim(left(comments, charindex('$', comments + '$') - 1)),
             stuff(comments, 1, charindex('$', comments + '$') - 1, ''))
     ) v (comments, rest)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: This does not generate an error in db<>fiddle:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=dd24cd452592a1c2a1956a2f8a2a1b5f.

Comment: Gordon. your script is absolutely fine. I do not know why its not running on my end. I appreciate for your quick  response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just another option is to use a bit of JSON

**Example or [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=ece5ae32ac8e10e7e8e3b94ff03a0085)**

```
Select A.ID 
      ,Comments= JSON_VALUE(S,'$[0]')
      ,Amount  = JSON_VALUE(S,'$[1]')
 From YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values ( '["'+replace(replace(replace([Comments],'-',' '),'$',' '),' ','","')+'"]' ) ) B(S)
```

**Results**

```
ID  Comments    Amount
1   John        123
2   Bret        45
3   HELEN       150
4   NULL        NULL
```